# how do I select AVG of multiple columns on a single row

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I select average of multiple columns?

Suppose I have some data like:

```
X   Y    Z
-------------
6   3    3
5   5    NULL
4   5    6
11  7    8
```

I want to get something like

```
AVG
-------------
4
5
5
8.66666667
```

I tried `select avg(x, y, z) from table`

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas on a query to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
 Select     (Coalesce(x,0) + Coalesce(y,0) + Coalesce(z,0)) /
       (Coalesce(x/x, 0) + Coalesce(y/y, 0) + Coalesce(z/z, 0))
```

or

```
 Select (Coalesce(x,0) + Coalesce(y,0) + Coalesce(z,0)) /
         (Case When x Is Null 0 Else 1 End +
          Case When y Is Null 0 Else 1 End +
          Case When z Is Null 0 Else 1 End)
```

Comment: The x/x technique is particularly slick.

Comment: Thanks for the response;
One more thing. Maybe it should be different question. But here it is anyway. Is it better (performance wise) to do this on the sql server? or to calculate it with the scripting language?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it matters enough to worry about. More important issue would be which is more maintainable and provides more clarity to future developers. But, I'd test it both ways to see. I'm frankly not sure. Most Performance issues are from Disk I/O, not from processing (CPU Cycles) and both approaches will have the same DIsk IO... One will have a few more CPU Cycles on the Database server, and the other a few more on the client...

Comment: how about devided by 0 exception?

Answer (score 3):

You add them up, and divide by the number of values.  The exclusion of NULLs from the denominator of the average operation is a little tricky:

```
SELECT (IFNULL(x, 0) + IFNULL(y, 0) + IFNULL(z, 0)) /
       (IIF(ISNULL(x), 0, 1) + IIF(ISNULL(y), 0, 1) + IIF(ISNULL(z), 0, 1))
  FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(x + y + z) / 3
```

Comment: No, I think what OP wants is an average of the values in each record.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood the question. Updated my response with something that might work - although if there are NULLs that complicates things a bit...