# to calculate MAX , SUM, AVERAGE from several columns (fields) in ACCESS 2013

Tags: function, max, aggregate, average, multiple-columns

I have the following table in access:

```
    entity ratingA ratingB ratingC 
    XYZ     0-100   0-100   0-100
    ABC     0-100   0-100   0-100
```

I need to get a query to do some simple aggregate functions (SUM, MAX, AVE) out of every 3 columns for each entity (fields: ratingA, ratingB, ratingC), but the builtin function only do this for one field at once, not for several fields/columns.

Comment: see the second solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not actually my own solution, I found here [how do I select AVG of multiple columns on a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268760/how-do-i-select-avg-of-multiple-columns-on-a-single-row) similar for mysql and adopted it for access (as there is not function ISNULL):

```
   (NZ(RatingA, 0) + NZ(RatingB, 0) + NZ(RatingC, 0)) /
   (IIF(ISNULL(RatingA), 0, 1) + IIF(ISNULL(RatingB), 0, 1) + IIF(ISNULL(RatingC), 0, 1))
```

I put it as a calculated field in new query grouped by field ENTITY.

Comment: Is it an update to your question? Or doing this provided an answer to your question?

Comment: this provides solution for my question (at least for most difficult AVERAGE) , SUM was not a problem at all.

Comment: Well if it is an answer, it will be helpful if you accept this answer which will in turn help others who are looking for the same type of problem. Self learning and self answering is welcome in this community.

Answer (score 1):

what you really have to do to get the average of several fields is first, find out how may combinations of the ways the fields can be filled. ex 3 fields can be filled 8 ways 
1,0,0 - 0,1,0, - 0,0,1 - 1,1,0 - 1,0,1 - 0,1,1  - 1,1,1 - 0,0,0 where 0 represents a null field if all the fields are filled you may force and argument to sum the fields and divide by the 3 however if only 2 or one field is filled then you have to first recognize the null fields and do not add them into the calculation. For example where there are two null fields then your average = the value of the field that contains a value. if two fields are full then your average =  the value of the sum of the two fields divided by two ect. so what you want to do is count the null fields in that record and then subtract the number of null fields from the number of fields being averaged. Sum the fields up and divide by that value :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the real code for it but here is some Pseudo:

```
SELECT RatingA+RatingB+RatingC/3 AS average
WHERE entity = XYZ
```

With group by for all entities:

```
SELECT RatingA+RatingB+RatingC/3 AS average
GROUP BY entity
```

Even better is:

```
TABLE
ENTITY     VALUE    RATINGTYPE
XYZ        7        A
XYZ        3        B
XYZ        5        C
ABC        4        A
ABC        4        D
```

Then you have infinte amount of type if you plan to expand in the future.

```
SELECT rating/count(rating) AS average
WHERE entity = XYZ
(AND TYPE = A) #If you want to sort by only one type.
```

Comment: thanks, but this as I understand will force to type a seperate query for each entity. Is there a way to make it for all entities with on query?

Comment: this solution does not solve issue with null values. This solution might do, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268760/how-do-i-select-avg-of-multiple-columns-on-a-single-row

Comment: Well the best solution is to have Entity Rating and then 3 rows with **Entity XYZ Rating A**, **Entity XYZ Rating B**, **Entity XYZ Rating C**. Then the amount of ratingtypes is not an issue if you plan to expand. Editing the solution above.

Comment: thanks, I already used flattening of multiple columns into 1 column, but still as a result of further queries you end up with several columns like one listed above.

Comment: So its a deadend? How is the structure now and why do you get several columns?