# How to get the average from multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I saw this answer [how do I select AVG of multiple columns on a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268760/how-do-i-select-avg-of-multiple-columns-on-a-single-row) but I have some rows which is the value is 0 and it's throwing an `error division by zero` when I try to use his

```
select (COALESCE(q1,0)+COALESCE(q2,0)+COALESCE(q3,0)+COALESCE(q4,0) / (COALESCE(q1/q1,0)+COALESCE(q2/q2,0)+COALESCE(q3/q3,0)+COALESCE(q4/q4,0) from table1
```

ex.

```
q1  q2  q3   q4
10  5   NULL 0
8   5   5    NULL
5   5   5    5
--------------
7.5
6
5
```

Comment: So you want to ignore `NULL` values and values that are `0` for the average? I find that a bit strange. I would expect the average of the first row to be 5

Comment: yes I want to ignore both NULL and 0 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the task, you can use `CASE` expression because you cannot divide by zero:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(q1,0) + COALESCE(q2,0) + COALESCE(q3,0) + COALESCE(q4,0)) / COALESCE((COALESCE(q1/(CASE WHEN q1 is null or q1= 0 then 1 else q1 end),0) +  COALESCE(q2/(CASE WHEN q2 is null or q2 = 0 then 1 else q2 end),0) +  COALESCE(q3/(CASE WHEN q3 is null or q3 = 0 then 1 else q3 end),0) +  COALESCE(q4/(CASE WHEN q4 is null or q4 = 0 then 1 else q4 end),0)),1)
 FROM table1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9jjYz23_)

It is added extra `COALESCE` because the sum of the divisor can be zero as well

Comment: I'm trying to understand the case expression part in q4 which is null means (0/1),0 is that right?

Comment: that's right because the divisor cannot be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the columns into rows then use `avg()` as an aggregate on those rows:

```
select (select avg(x.val) filter (where x.val > 0)
        from (values (t.q1),(t.q2),(t.q3),(t.q4) 
       ) as x(val)) as avg
from the_table t
```

alternatively this can be expressed with a lateral cross join:

```
select p.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     select avg(x.val) filter (where x.val > 0)
     from (
       values (t.q1),(t.q2),(t.q3),(t.q4) 
     ) as x(val)
  ) p
```

Instead of using `avg (x.val) filter(...)` you can also use `avg(nullif(x.val,0))`

Answer (score -1):

you are qualescing q4/q4 which is 0/0

i gave it a try and this is the query that worked, converting the value to bool first (true/false) and then converting that to an int is the safer option if you expect a lot of null and zero values:

```
select (
    COALESCE(q1::real, 0::real)+
    COALESCE(q2::real, 0::real)+
    COALESCE(q3::real, 0::real)+
    COALESCE(q4::real, 0::real)
)
/
(
   COALESCE((q1::bool)::int,0)+
   COALESCE((q2::bool)::int,0)+
   COALESCE((q3::bool)::int,0)+
   COALESCE((q4::bool)::int,0)
) from vals;
```